# Align: How to trim spaces from block selection to start of text?

Tags: regex, vim, alignment, spaces

I often find myself left aligning text within other text.
I know there are plugins to align columns but within a lot of other text it is not the easiest way.

This is my text:

```
>...this is text               X      more text
>...this is more text          X          more text
>...text text text             X               more text
>...this is text               X       more text
>...this is more text          X     more text
```

What I want to do is select a block of a single column (`X` in above example) and delete all spaces between my block and the text starting after the block.

What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Visually select the text to align, then use this ex command: `'<,'>s/\%Xv\s*//`
 (substitute X by the block column number of your choice. )

- `'<,'>` defines the range for the substitute command,
- `\%Xv` is the zero-width regex pattern to locate a specific column, check `:help pattern`

Comment: Yes a great solution! I'm trying to put this in a map but without success: `map <silent> <F5> <ESC>:let r = col(".")<CR>gv:exe "s/\\%".r."v\\s*//"<CR>` First select block (`X`), then <ESC> in order to capture column, gv again to reselect block, then execute your command. What is wrong here? :(

Comment: Try this: `noremap <F9> <ESC>:let r = col(".")<CR>:exe "'<,'>s/\\%".r."v\\s*//"<CR>` the problem is, in visual mode, ex command line will automatically prepend `'<,'>`, so what vim sees is actually `'<,'>exe "'<,'>s/\\%".r."v\\s*//"` which results in an error. And I suggest to always prefer noremap when mapping, unless you want recursive behavior intentionally. I have swapped `:` and `;`, so this is a must for me. Besides, `:no` is one keystroke less than `:map` :)

Comment: I suppose this will be my most used map :) Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Not a find and replace solution but how about

- placing the cursor on the starting position
- <kbd>9</kbd><kbd>9</kbd><kbd>@</kbd><kbd>=</kbd><kbd>"</kbd><kbd>d</kbd><kbd>w</kbd><kbd>j</kbd><kbd>"</kbd>

**Breakdown**

- <kbd>d</kbd><kbd>w</kbd>:  d(elete) w(ord) *(deletes all white space until the beginning of the next wordt)*
- <kbd>j</kbd>:   and go to next line
- <kbd>9</kbd><kbd>9</kbd><kbd>@</kbd>: 99 times

Comment: Just to be clearer, 'dw' on an empty space, will delete all the white spaces until the beginning of the next word.

Comment: @XavierT. - Thx, much better. I've added your comment to the answer.